# Update Flurry in Xcode

Tags: xcode, flurry

I am trying to update Flurry SDK for IOS8. I try to delete all relevant links to Flurry, but I still can not add file to project with he new SDK. "Tells me the is a still a folder named Flurry in the project"
What am I missing, what is the proper way to do this as I will have other apps to update?
Is there a small program available to do this job?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check you project folder in Finder, may be when you choose removing option, you use "Remove Reference" and not the "Move to Trash".

Answer (score 0):

[image: XcodeView]

Make sure you *really* deleted the Flurry folder. Use "Show in  Finder" (see screenshot) and delete it from there from within your project folder. Then:

-In the Finder, drag the Flurry SDK into your project’s file folder. 
-Now add it to your project: File > Add Files to “YOUR PROJECT”
-Add SystemConfiguration.framework to your app. This is required for Reachability to manage network operations efficiently.